# Empty $_POST variable webservice response

Tags: php, html, web-services, post, get

I am communicating with a web service server that after a payment is completed the server sends me a response as a `$_POST` variable. If I try to `print_r($_POST)` it appears to be empty, but when I write the variables to a text file the file shows me the values. My goal is to build an to execute a link that will complete the user's order. Since the $_POST value is only visible in the text file, I am reading the link from the text file and trying execute a redirect, but when the other page is reached the $_GET variables are empty. I have previously tried to recover the raw $_POST variables with `file_get_contents("php://input")` with no success. Here is my actual code:

```
<?php   
ob_start();
// let's get the online response parameters...  
$_VTransactionID = $_POST["VTransactionID"];
$_VAccountId = $_POST["VAccountId"];
$_VTotalAmount = $_POST["VTotalAmount"];
$_VPaymentMethod = $_POST["VPaymentMethod"];
$_VPaymentDescription = $_POST["VPaymentDescription"];
$_VAuthorizationNum = $_POST["VAuthorizationNum"];
$_VConfirmationNum = $_POST["VConfirmationNum"];
$_VMerchantTransId = $_POST["VMerchantTransId"];

////////Write LInk to file////////////////////////////////////
$fp = fopen("debug/OnlineResponseLog.log","w");

$link = "testvar.php?order_id=".$_VAccountId."&code=000&error=false&TxnGUID=".$_VConfirmationNum."\n\r";

if($fp){
    fwrite($fp,$link);
    fclose($fp);
}else{
    printf("error while trying to write on online response Log");
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////REad LINK////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$fp = fopen("debug/OnlineResponseLog.log","r");
if($fp){
    $cad = fread($fp,filesize("debug/OnlineResponseLog.log"));
    fclose($fp);
}else{
    printf("error while trying to read online response Log");
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = $cad;
//To check if values where stored. Last char is used because last characters are supposed to be digits and not an equal sign.
$lastchar = substr($url, -1);
if($lastchar == "=")  
         $url ="testvar.php?order_id=&code=999&error=true&TxnGUID="; 

header("Location: $url");
//////////////////  
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. All the file writing can be avoided if the `$_POST` values were visible at `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_REQUEST` global variable.  The `$_POST` variable is only populated if the data was "posted" and `$_GET` is only populated when the HTTP query string is sent.  `$_REQUEST` is populated by both methods.  However, you should be more wary of insertion attacks during `FORM` posting so sanitation/validation of user important remains critical when using `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I print_r($_REQUEST) and only got this: Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 6cd4c9d60fe4a9781a3df44b9be330c7 [osCAdminID] => 99e6d3f63b43926c5d6a9b48c3e6b686 [osCsid] => 1accc93fc5a96accab5802dd703742a8 )

Answer (score 0):

i guess your post variables are not empty .. you cant see anything because of this

```
ob_start();
```

remove the function while testing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed the the ob_start() but still no luck.

Comment: ok now i got what you trying to do ... so you dont actually send request to the page, do you?.... some other server sends post request to you and your trying to view what actually being sent using print_r?? if this is the scenario then you can't ..... your page is serving request to the server which sends post request and it will serve that server not to your page...

Comment: yes! that's exactly the scenario. What is the correct way to handle this? I already achieved a work around, but if a better approach is given I'll implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by separating the tasks in two separate php files. One file that writes the constructed link with the $_POST variables to a file and redirects to a second file that reads the link from the file and redirects to the corresponding page.